# Angular 2 bind HTML inputs to component variables like in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, vue.js, binding

So I've been struggling with this for a long time...I've been looking into the docs, but there are so many different directives and ways to communicate between components and the DOM, but only a few good examples...

So I'm actually not even sure what I need. Let's say I have a user input in my **tables.component.html** file like this:

```
<label>Name</label>
<input id="customerName" class="form-control" required>
```

Then there is my **tables.component.ts** file which looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { isLoggedIn } from '../../assets/js/auth.js';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tables',
  templateUrl: './tables.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tables.component.css']
})

export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {

  customers = [];

  id = ""; // keep outside of object to prevent user changes
  customer_form = {
    name: "",
    job: "",
    address: "",
    birthdate: "",
    email: "",
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ...
}
```

To make it simple: I want to bind the user input above to the customer_form.name variable in my component. I'm looking for the equivalent of Vue 2.0 models, so that if the user changes the input value, the component value changes aswell. I don't neccessarily have to push the data within a form since we've got the task not to set up any backend...

Anyway, I'm kinda confused. I read the docs, but that made it just worse. One page says I'm supposed to add a controller to the form and add a script to the bottom of the HTML, another one said I have to make a template of the form that should be stored in the component...And then there are so many different directives to bind things. I was assuming you'd want to use ngModel for that, but I couldn't seem to get that working like in the examples I found.

Thanks for any help in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple example of binding in a template-driven form: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2tkrf

Note that **FormsModule** is imported in **app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';         //<---- IMPORTED

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './hero-form/hero-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule                 //<---- IMPORTED IN MODULE
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroFormComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: So...importing the FormsModule did something! I actually didn't see that in any of the docs. However, I'm getting this issue: "If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions."

Should I now add a name tag or rather add model options for the standalone? I'm not sure if that affects it in any 

Edit: I'm a stupid idiot. I just had to import the Module and give the input literally ANY name. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The best way to fix your problem is to add a name attribute to you <input> like so: `<input [(ngModel)]="model.userName" name="userName">`. The value you use as a tag name should be unique among the form. The 'standalone' option is being used very seldom and could be useful for rare cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is `[(ngModel)]` which is used for two-way data binding.

```
<input 
  id="customerName" 
  class="form-control" 
  required 
  [(ngModel)]="customer_form.name"
  name="name">
```

PS: To use the `[(ngModel)]`, you'll have to import `FormsModule` and then add it the the `imports` array of your `AppModule` or whatever module you're using it in.

```
...
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ..., 
    FormsModule, 
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I tried that already...that always gives me an error in the Web console saying "can't bind to <property> since it isn't a known property"...

Comment: Did you import the `FormsModule` and add it to the `imports` array of your `@NgModule({})`

Comment: Nope I didn't....and you also have to give the input a name...god knows why. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

```
Use ngModel for two-way data binding
put [(ngModel)] on the input to pass the data from & to your property like this:


//app.module code
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';         //<---- IMPORTED

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { TablesComponent } from './tables.component';  //<---- IMPORTED

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule                 //<---- IMPORTED IN MODULE
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TablesComponent    //<---- IMPORTED
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
//--------------------------tables.component.html
    <input id="customerName" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="customer_form.name" required>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I already told the other guy with the same answer, I got that error that it can't bind to it..

Comment: it work fine with me i tried it ... make sure that you had imported the component in your app.module and put it in declarations

Comment: I did...but it didn't do anything. However, as Mikhail suggested above, importing the formsmodule kind of did something, but I'm getting the Error I posted above. Could it be that I have to specify a certain name for an input, even though I don't send it to a server?

Comment: make sure if your app.module contain TablesComponent & FormsModule -                               i want to see your html code and app.module code