# Plain English for #something="ngModel"

Tags: angular

Based on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2tkrf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-form%2Fhero-form.component.html, modified slightly:

.ts

```
export class page
{
  model = {mm: "Inside model"}; // my understanding is 'model' is not a required object for binding.
  X = "xxx";  // wired with display via [(ngModel)]="X"
  Y = "yyy";     
  mm="Outside of model";
}
```

.html

```
Binding: 
        <input type="text"
               required name="bogus123"
               [(ngModel)]="X"
               #Y="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="Y.valid || Y.pristine">
          A value is required
        </div>
        <div>
          X value ="{{X}}"
        </div>
```

it works out great
[image]

**Here is my understanding:**

`required name="bogus123"` are HTML attribute for **input** tag despite what's in next `<div>`, out of picture of discussion.

`[(ngModel)]="X"` means to 2-way bind this input box with local variable named `X` inside .ts

Thought `#X="ngModel"` is another way to wired this input box with variable `X` in .ts, but get

> "Cannot assign to a reference or variable!"

Replacing `Y` with `mm` in .html works. Already studied these two SO
[What is the difference between the #name and [(ngModel)]="name" in Angular2 Form input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234559/what-is-the-difference-between-the-name-and-ngmodel-name-in-angular2-form)

[Angular 2 bind HTML inputs to component variables like in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924363/angular-2-bind-html-inputs-to-component-variables-like-in-vue)

Can someone explain what is `#something="ngModel"` in plain English without "directive" and "component"?

Answer (score 4):

First, `#X="ngModel"` is **not** another way to bind ngModel to your local variable X from `.ts`.

TLDR: It will bind the instance of Angular directive `ngModel` to a new *template variable* `X` that has nothing to do with your `.ts` variable. A template variable is only available in the `.html` of your component (unless you use `@ViewChild` or similar to get a reference in your `.ts`).

So when you attempt:

```html
<input type="text"
    required name="bogus123"
    [(ngModel)]="X"
    #X="ngModel">
```

You get this error: `Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "X". Template variables are read-only.`

You create a new template variable `X` that hold the instance of the directive `NgModel`. Then Angular try to do two-way binding on this new template variable `X` and won't let you cause you cannot reassign template variable. They are read only.

### Explanation of `#something` syntax

The syntax `#something` is used to get a reference to some element or component in the template. It bind the variable `something` to the element it's applied to, not the other way around.

If the element is a component (`<app-child #something></app-child>`), the template variable `something` will be assigned with the instance of the component `ChildComponent`. If you already have a variable `something` in your `.ts`, the variable from the template will not modify it. Instead a new one with the same name is created, thus hiding the other variables. Angular prioritize the template variable over those from your component.

Similarly, if the element is a basic html element (`<input type="text" #myInput`), the variable `myInput` will be assigned to an [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Example:

You have a component app-child:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '<span *ngIf="expanded">Hello world!</span>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  expanded = false;

  toggle() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
}
```

Now in your app component template:

```html
<div>
  <app-child #child></app-child>
  <button type="button" (click)="child.toggle()">Toggle</button>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" #input value="Input test" />
  <button type="button" (click)="input.select()">Select input text</button>
</div>
```

### Now for `#something="ngModel"` syntax

This syntax allow you to get a reference to a directive instead of a component when you normally wouldn't be able to.

If you have in your app component template something like this:

```html
<app-child #var appMy></app-child>
```

Now `var` will hold your `ChildComponent` component instance, but let's say you wanted to have a reference to your `MyDirective` (`appMy`) instead? That's where you'd need the different syntax.

To get a reference to your directive, you need to add an `exportAs` to it first:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMy]',
  exportAs: 'myDirective' // <-- Added exportAs here
})
export class MyDirective {}
```

Now the `exportAs` tell Angular that your directive will be available under `myDirective` and you can now do this to get a reference:

```html
<app-child #var="myDirective" appMy></app-child>
```

`var` will now hold an instance of `MyDirective` instead of `AppChildComponent`.

If you check the source code for the [ngModel directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts), you can see that it is exported as `ngModel`:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])',
  providers: [formControlBinding],
  exportAs: 'ngModel'
})
export class NgModel
```

Here's a stackblitz with some of these exemples: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pagmze

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know you said not to use 'directive' or 'component' but they're core concepts of the Angular framework so you'll have to excuse me.

First let's look at just `#Y`.

In the context of an Angular component template, `#` denotes a [template reference](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables). These can exist in 2 forms:

- Globally (meaning they are available to component controller via [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild))
- Scoped - inside of a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) (ie. inside of an *ngIf, *ngFor, *ngTemplateOutlet, etc..)

So, basically `#Y` is creating a reference to the `<input>` element which has a type of [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). If you look at the type definition for that element, you'll notice that it has no `valid` or `pristine` properties/getters. That is because the element is actually inheriting those properties/getters from the [`NgModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) directive which is ultimately inheriting those properties from the [`AbstractControlDirective`](http://AbstractControlDirective) which all comes from Angular.

So then, the million dollar question, why do we need `#Y="ngModel"`? And the simplest answer is type-casting. All that additional piece of code is doing is telling your template to treat the template reference as if it were an `NgModel` directive - which it is! And so instead of getting the accessing the HTMLInputElement's properties, you can instead access the NgModel's properties.

And so, there you have it. Hope that helps clear it up for you.